# Perform MaxPool1D on 2D features (Iris Dataset)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I want to use MaxPoo1D for a dense layer in the neural network model below but I got this error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer max_pooling1d_8 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 128)
```

why am I getting this error and how can I fix this?
and why is the expected ndim = 3?

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris

iris = load_iris()

X = iris.data
y = iris.target
features = iris.feature_names

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)

stdscr = StandardScaler()
stdscr.fit(X_train)
X_train = stdscr.transform(X_train)
X_test = stdscr.transform(X_test)

one = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)
one.fit(y_train.reshape(-1, 1))
y_train = one.transform(y_train.reshape(-1, 1))
y_test = one.transform(y_test.reshape(-1, 1))

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(128, activation="relu"))
model.add(layers.MaxPool1D())
model.add(layers.Dense(32, activation="relu"))
model.add(layers.Dense(3, activation="softmax"))

model.compile(optimizer="Adam", loss="CategoricalCrossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])

history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=30, batch_size=16, validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add another dimension along which to perform the convolution.

Try:

```
X_train = tf.expand_dims(X_train, axis=-1)
```

Then, you will end up with 3D data, which will not work with your loss function. So you need to flatten it, for instance with `tf.keras.layers.Flatten`.

Full running code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, OneHotEncoder
iris = load_iris()

X = iris.data
y = iris.target
features = iris.feature_names

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)

stdscr = StandardScaler()
stdscr.fit(X_train)
X_train = stdscr.transform(X_train)
X_test = stdscr.transform(X_test)

X_train = tf.expand_dims(X_train, axis=-1)
X_test = tf.expand_dims(X_test, axis=-1) 

one = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)
one.fit(y_train.reshape(-1, 1))
y_train = one.transform(y_train.reshape(-1, 1))
y_test = one.transform(y_test.reshape(-1, 1))

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation="relu"))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool1D())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation="relu"))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation="softmax"))

model.compile(optimizer="Adam", loss="CategoricalCrossentropy", 
              metrics=["accuracy"])

history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=30, 
                    batch_size=16, validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
```

Comment: thank you very much! can you explain a few things for me? Why does it have to be 3 dimensional even though its maxpooling 1D? is it for a mathematical reason or tensorflow is simply built that way? Another question is that the input shape is [120, 4, 1] and the output shape for the first dense layer is [None, 4, 128] but where is the 4 from? I understand 128 is because thats the #neurons I specified. Is it 4 because # features is 4?